# this.state.results.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

Trying to take the data from https://api.rawg.io/api/games/portal-2 and display it on the page.
Is it because the API is providing me with an object that .map wont deal with?
If that's the case what could I do to make it an array instead

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


class List extends Component {
  state = {
    results: []
  }

componentDidMount() {
const url = `${`https://api.rawg.io/api/games/portal-2`}`;
axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
.then((data) => {
    this.setState({ results: data })
    console.log("Hello" + this.state.data)
    })
.catch(function (error) {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
  } else if (error.request) {
    console.log(error.request);
  } else {
    console.log('Error', error.message);
  }
});

}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
        <h1>List of Games</h1>
        {this.state.results.map((games) => (
          <li>{games.results}</li>
        ))}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List
```

Error message

```
TypeError: this.state.results.map is not a function
 32 | 
  33 |    return (
  34 |        <div>
> 35 |        <h1>List of Games</h1>
     | ^  36 |        {this.state.results.map((games) => (
  37 |          <li>{games.results}</li>
  38 |        ))}
```

If anyone has any idea that would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you share an example of the object being returned from API?

Comment: You're setting `results` to `data` from axios – are you sure that that is an array?

Comment: The API is not returning an Array and hence map isn't working. (It is kind of wierd why the API isn't returning an Array of objects, which is the normal way of sending data) You can try using destructuring: ie. Once you have the data, wrap it in an array. `[...data]`

Answer (score 1):

The `https://api.rawg.io/api/games/portal-2` API endpoint is not returning an array.

If you wish to display the "List of Games", you can use `https://api.rawg.io/api/games` It returns a JSON but with the "results" key having a list of games which I assume is what you want.

I recommend using a browser extension such as **[JSONView](https://jsonview.com/)** to better visualize the structure of the API response from your browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set result state to object, the response from your API is object, not array so that, react will throw this error.
Try set result state again (data.genres, data.platform... and so on)
[image]